# Imported classes from a jar file in JRuby conflict with top level core module

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have a JRuby project that is requiring a third-party .jar file containing several Java classes that I need to use. I am running into an issue where one of the classes is named Process which is conflicting with the top level Ruby Process module.

I have built a github repository with a minimal proof of concept that illustrates the issue: https://github.com/douglasmiller/process_test

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue? What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar to what you would do in Ruby to solve this - import it under a module (where it's used) or do not import it at all.

1. do not use `java_import org.process_test.Process` and use `org.process_test.Process::PROCESS_CONSTANT` directly
2. if you really want to import only import where it won't conflict :

`module MyApp
  java_import org.process_test.Process
  # MyApp::Process != ::Process
  class ProcessStuff
    def initialize; puts Process::PROCESS_CONSTANT end
  end
end`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My use of java_import was importing the Process class into the global namespace. I ended up defining a module and running: "include_package 'org.process_test'" to include the entire package.